# How can I make a function generic on an MLReader

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I am working in Spark 1.6.3. Here are two functions that do  the same thing:

```
def modelFromBytesCV(modelArray: Array[Byte]): CountVectorizerModel = {
  val tempPath: Path = KAZOO_TEMP_DIR.resolve(s"model_${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
  Files.write(tempPath, modelArray)
  CountVectorizerModel.read.load(tempPath.toString)
}

def modelFromBytesIDF(modelArray: Array[Byte]): IDFModel = {
  val tempPath: Path = KAZOO_TEMP_DIR.resolve(s"model_${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
  Files.write(tempPath, modelArray)
  IDFModel.read.load(tempPath.toString)
}
```

I would like to make these functions generic. What I am hung up on is that the common trait between the [CountVectorizerModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerModel$) object and IDFModel is MLReadable[T] which itself must take as a type either CountVectorizerModel or IDFModel. This is sort of a recursive parent class loop that I can't figure out a solution to.

By comparison, the generic model writer is easy, because MLWritable is a common trait extended by all the models I am interested in:

```
def modelToBytes[M <: MLWritable](model: M): Array[Byte] = {
  val tempPath: Path = KAZOO_TEMP_DIR.resolve(s"model_${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
  model.write.overwrite().save(tempPath.toString)
  Files.readAllBytes(tempPath)
}
```

How can I make a generic reader that will turn turn a spark-ml model into a byte array?

Comment: Note: the accepted solution answers the question in the title, but the code doesn't work because you can't write a model to and from a single file. A model is written to a folder; my full implementation involves tar-ing the folder and converting that to a byte array. Just be aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work you'll need access to a specific `MlReadable` object.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLReadable

def modelFromBytes[M](obj: MLReadable[M], modelArray: Array[Byte]): M = {
  val tempPath: Path = ???
  ...
  obj.read.load(tempPath.toString)
}
```

which could be later used as:

```
val bytes: Array[Byte] = ???
modelFromBytes(CountVectorizerModel, bytes)
```

Note that, despite the first appearance, there is nothing recursive here - `MLReadable[M]` refers to companion object, not class as such. So for example [`CountVectorizerModel` object](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerModel$) is `MLReadable`, while [`CountVectorizeModel` class](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerModel) isn't.

Internally, Spark `MLReader` handles this in a different way - [it creates an instance of the class using reflection](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0a4c03f7d084f1d2aa48673b99f3b9496893ce8d/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/util/ReadWrite.scala#L494-L496), and then [sets its `Params`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0a4c03f7d084f1d2aa48673b99f3b9496893ce8d/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/util/ReadWrite.scala#L497-L498). However this path won't be very useful for you here*.

If compatibility with the current API is required, you can try making readable object implicit:

```
def modelFromBytes[M](modelArray: Array[Byte])(implicit obj: MLReadable[M]): M = {
  ...
}
```

and then

```
implicit val readable: MLReadable[CountVectorizerModel] = CountVectorizerModel

modelFromBytes[CountVectorizerModel](bytes)
```

---

* Technically speaking it is possible to get companion object via reflection

```
def modelFromBytesCV[M <: MLWritable](
    modelArray: Array[Byte])(implicit ct: ClassTag[M]): M = {
  val tempPath: Path = ???
  ...
  val cls = Class.forName(ct.runtimeClass.getName + "$");
  cls.getField("MODULE$").get(cls).asInstanceOf[MLReadable[M]]
    .read.load(tempPath.toString)) 
}
```

but I don't think that is a path worth exploring here. In particular we cannot really provide strict type bounds here - using `MLWritable` is a hack to limit human errors, but is rather useless for compiler.